# Is it possible to zoom in on any text in an app in realtime?

Tags: zooming

I have an app that has tiny tiny writing that I need to read and I can't take a hundred screenshots to zoom in to read each one and the developer has yet to fix it but I was wondering if there was a way to have a magnifying thingy on top of this app and move it around the screen to enlarge whatever I can't read in realtime. Any tips?  And, the text is not able to be copied or pasted etc.

OS: 4.1
Phone: S3

Answer (score 2):

If your Android version is 4.1 (Jelly Bean) or greater, you can find magnification gestures under your system settings.

1. Go to *Settings*
2. *Accessibility*
3. *Magnification Gestures*

Info:

- [Magnification Gestures](http://www.abilitynet.org.uk/mcmw/magnification-gestures-android-jelly-bean-4-2-2/)
- [Usage](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2929058?hl=en)

Comment: I'm on an S3 on 4.1 which doesn't have magnification gestures. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It may/may not solve OP's problem depending on the OP's resources, but it could be helpful for the other android users for other alternatives. You could record the screen of your mobile using a screen recording app and view it on a large computer/tv screen to view the text clearly.

Alternatively, you could also use an emulator such as Bluestacks and install the app you want to zoom and view it on your computer screen or a projector to make the small objects and text clearly on a larger screen.